# SATA-III drive comaptiblity with current motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, upgrade, sata, compatibility

Next month I will be upgrading my computer with newer/better hard drive (Western Digital 250GB, 7200rpm, 32MB, Sata III, Caviar Blue, here is a link where I will buy it from - http://www.dateks.lv/cenas/23/50051_western_digital_250gb_7200rpm_32mb_sata_iii_caviar_blue.php), current specs:

```
Current Hard Disk Drive - WDC WD800JD-60JRC0 ATA Device
New Hard Disk Drive - WD2500AAKX
```

specs for new disk: http://wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=898&language=1
http://wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=110

```
Motherboard - Gigabyte GA-945PL-S3
CPU - DualCore Intel Core 2 Duo E4300, 1800 MHz (9 x 200)
DIMM1: Kingston (1 GB DDR2-667 DDR2 SDRAM)
DIMM3: 1 GB DDR2-533 DDR2 SDRAM
Operating System - Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
OS Version - 6.1.7601
OS Kernel Type - Multiprocessor Free (32-bit)
```

My current hard drive is 80 GB big but it is very slow, maximum 114 MB/s of read speed (buffered), 54 MB/s (linear read) and the random read is.. well random (duh). I don't know the write speeds. I am multi-tasker and I like to listen to YouTube music, program in Delphi and chat with somebody on Skype (doesn't stress the hard drive but my I do random things). I very hate that everything starts to lag and halt when disk is reading a lot of data, I can hear the disk activity or look at front panel hard drive led. Well anyways I will upgrade to this hard drive. I know there are already same questions asked but this confuses me. My [motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2325) supports only SATA-II disk drives. I was reading some reviews about this disk and people couldn't use this hard drive on motherboards with SATA-II connectors without jumper settings:

[image]

I want to use the maximum speed of SATA-II connector, I can use the `PHY` jumper settings. Also my case is not the best and it is very loud with very vibrating disks, but this drive has a `IntelliSeek` technology so it helps to make hard drive less vibrate. I don't know if this hard drive will even run on this motherboard, well I think it will work, it just has to work. By the way I don't need a lot of space. I plenty enough money to buy this hard drive, but please could somebody aprove/comment my decission.

**Main question: "Will it work?"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SATA II is 3.0Gb/s.  SATA III is 6.0Gb/s.  Just making sure you get that.  Now, you read on some sites that some people had to set the PHY jumper to limit the drive to 3.0gb/s (SATA II) in order to use it with motherboards that came with SATA II connectors.  Ok.  So...

Your old drive, according to WD was SATA I.  [Read here](http://support.wdc.com/product/install.asp?groupid=603&lang=en).  It is the same speed drive, as far as the rotation speed is concerned.  So, based on just the data transfer speed, the new drive will be twice as fast.

Will it work?  As long as you set the jumper at 5-6, there is no reason why it shouldn't.  If you really want to try to cut down on vibration at the hard drive, try putting a couple of strips of electrical tape on each side of the drive (don't forget to reveal the screw holes) so act as a buffer between the drive and the bracket.

Comment: "So, based on just the data transfer speed, the new drive will be twice as fast."  Unfortunately, it is entirely possible that the SATA bus is not the bottleneck here.  (I realize that your statement reads correctly but I wanted to add emphasis here - *based on the data transfer speed*.)

Comment: You are very correct.  I was wrong to say "will be" and should have stated that it "could be up to" instead.  I was not thinking about the speed as much as I was looking at compatibility.